# Is there a timetable of dates for Project Catalyst phases/cycles?

Tags: catalyst

I am looking for the most reliable and official way to find:

- Next date Project Catalyst starts a new cycle
- Dates for the phases in the current cycle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess this is what you are looking for

https://cardanocataly.st/funds/

Answer (score 1):

As you can find [here](https://iohk.io/en/blog/posts/2020/09/16/project-catalyst-introducing-our-first-public-fund-for-cardano-community-innovation/) there is a link to [IdeaScale portal](https://cardano.ideascale.com/a/index) and link to [Telegram chat group](https://t.me/cardanocatalyst) in which they announce all new events (Crowdcast, Fund cycles, etc.).

Basically every 6 weeks we have a fund round but sometimes because of technical or other reasons there are delays (as with Fund 4).

You can also subscribe to the email newsletter to receive the latest updates or to check in [Cardano forum](https://forum.cardano.org/tag/project-catalyst).

Comment: I am looking for a resource that can simply be looked at anytime to get the dates.  The sources you list depend on active monitoring or scrolling back through announcements to determine the current dates.

Comment: This is the current situation. Once there are other resources I will update the answer.

Comment: Here you can also find more information about the different events via Crowdcast: https://www.crowdcast.io/iohk